# Truffle test - Timeout during out-of-the-box metacoin.js test

Tags: truffle, testing

Been trying to get the standard init tests to work for a couple of hours, but no joy.  Would be grateful for any assistance.

Steps taken so far

```
truffle init
```

Fine.  So far, so good.

```
truffle compile
```

Still OK.

```
truffle migrate
```

Success.

```
truffle test
```

Problems.  Seem to have tried everything.

```
  Contract: MetaCoin
    1) "before all" hook: prepare suite


  0 passing (2m)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: MetaCoin "before all" hook: prepare suite:
     Error: timeout of 120000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

This seems like it could be a Mocha issue, but the metacoin.js code is off-the-shelf source from Consensys...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit: Had similar problem, when connected to EthereumJS TestRPC tests pass just fine. So perhaps this is just network timeout.

Comment: Cheers wonglik!  TestRPC works a treat for me, too.  Just had my heart set on seeing it work with geth, too, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main author of Truffle here. It's likely related to how fast your Ethereum client is processing blocks. Truffle assumes deployment will take no longer than two minutes during tests, but I have heard reports that when deploying to the morden testnet it can often take far longer. If it does, it can cause `truffle test` to mark the test as failed and throw an error, as you're seeing above.

We have a ticket filed for this very issue: https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle/issues/261

Cheers!

Comment: Wow, Tim.  A little star struck over here.  No need to introduce yourself.  Of course I know who you are!

I'm running against geth on a private chain, but that is runniing in a VM with limited resources.  So, I'm definitely exceeding 120 seconds, but that's also the case for truffle migrate , and there's no timeout there.  In any case, Test RPC is like a hot knife through butter, so I'm up-and-running anyway. 

My first week using Truffle, and I'm really starting to fly with Smart Contract dev.  Thank you for your work, well done.

Comment: "that's also the case for truffle migrate, and there's no timeout there" -- correct! I actually answered the question incorrectly. It's not due to block time, but rather the total time it takes to deploy all contracts. `truffle test` uses `truffle migrate` for deployment, which has no maximum timeout, but the test runner (mocha) enforces a timeout to ensure the test doesn't run indefinitely. I'll edit my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Hard coded mocha.js timeout to 0.  Hardly an elegant solution, but it seems to have gotten me over the hump.  Truffle test now executes!

Comment: Could you add details for this please @Max?